# What are common western saloon instruments?

Tags: history, instruments, country-and-western

This is a question that popped in my mind, but the funny thing is, I couldn't think of a lot of instruments that played during the Western Saloon period.

Here's all I can think of:

- Upright Piano (out of tune)
- Accordion
- Harmonica
- Clarinet (not sure)

What other instruments played during this time period?

Comment: "(out of tune)"-- The most important part.

Comment: Don’t forget the tack piano (thumbtacks in the hammers).  Classic sound.  Our college had one for film scoring class.

Comment: Put that time period in terms of years.  It will affect what kind of accordion existed.

Comment: @RichardBarber isn't that a bit of a cliché though? Saloons would more likely have had just _badly maintained_ pianos – which may in some cases have sounded a bit like tack- or honky tonk pianos, but hardly on purpose.

Comment: @leftaroundabout not only did saloons need and have tack pianos from the late 19th century, regular uprights could be fitted with a moveable sheet with brass tack heads.

Answer (score 1):

To add to your list:

- Upright Piano
- Accordion
- Harmonica
- Acoustic Guitar
- Banjo
- Violin (Fiddle)

Comment: Any source would be interesting; what strikes me is the absence of anything in direction of percussion as at least belt with bells?